# Magento 2 : Unable to Run Integration Tests

Tags: magento2, testing, phpunit

I have a fresh installation of magento2 enterprise on my server, and just to get a feel for how unit tests work. I attempted to run these tests by executing following command. But before I executed this command, I did update `dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php.dist` with correct database credentials.

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist
```

After running command, All I was given in response is unable to read `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist` file. Event I change permission using `chmod` to 777 and tried again, but same result happened.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post with error i displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the tests inside `dev/tests/integration`, specifying the configuration file is not enough.

I did not yet figure out why exactly, but somewhere paths relative to the current working directory are used.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try passing an absolute path to the config file?

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit -c `pwd`/dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist
```